# How can I modify a collection while also iterating over it?

Tags: collections, iterator, rust, immutability

I have a `Board` (a.k.a. `&mut Vec<Vec<Cell>>`) which I would like to update while iterating over it. The new value I want to update with is derived from a function which requires a `&Vec<Vec<Cell>>` to the collection I'm updating.

I have tried several things:

1. Use `board.iter_mut().enumerate()` and `row.iter_mut().enumerate()` so that I could update the `cell` in the innermost loop. Rust does not allow calling the `next_gen` function because it requires a `&Vec<Vec<Cell>>` and you cannot have a immutable reference when you already have a mutable reference.
2. Change the `next_gen` function signature to accept a `&mut Vec<Vec<Cell>>`. Rust does not allow multiple mutable references to an object.

I'm currently deferring all the updates to a `HashMap` and then applying them after I've performed my iteration:

```
fn step(board: &mut Board) {
    let mut cells_to_update: HashMap<(usize, usize), Cell> = HashMap::new();
    for (row_index, row) in board.iter().enumerate() {
        for (column_index, cell) in row.iter().enumerate() {
            let cell_next = next_gen((row_index, column_index), &board);
            if *cell != cell_next {
                cells_to_update.insert((row_index, column_index), cell_next);
            }
        }
    }

    println!("To Update: {:?}", cells_to_update);
    for ((row_index, column_index), cell) in cells_to_update {
        board[row_index][column_index] = cell;
    }
}
```

[Full source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea4b440c9bf77f49592e#file-main-rs-L53)

Is there a way that I could make this code update the `board` "in place", that is, inside the innermost loop while still being able to call `next_gen` inside the innermost loop?

**Disclaimer**:

I'm learning Rust and I know this is not the best way to do this. I'm playing around to see what I can and cannot do. I'm also trying to limit any copying to restrict myself a little bit. As [oli_obk - ker mentions, this implementation for Conway's Game of Life is flawed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966867/modify-collection-while-iterating-over-it#comment49966671_30967411).

This code was intended to gauge a couple of things:

1. if this is even possible
2. if it is idiomatic Rust

From what I have gathered in the comments, it is possible with `std::cell::Cell`. However, using `std:cell:Cell` circumvents some of the core Rust principles, which I described as my "dilemma" in the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way that I could make this code update the board "in place"?

There exists a type specially made for situations such as these. It's coincidentally called [`std::cell::Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html). You're allowed to mutate the contents of a `Cell` even when it has been immutably borrowed multiple times. `Cell` is limited to types that implement `Copy` (for others you have to use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), and if multiple threads are involved then you must use an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) in combination with somethinng like a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html)).

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let board = vec![Cell::new(0), Cell::new(1), Cell::new(2)];

    for a in board.iter() {
        for b in board.iter() {
            a.set(a.get() + b.get());
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", board);
}
```

Comment: as the documentation states, *interior mutability is something of a last resort*, and I do believe there are other avenues to explore before falling back to cell types

Comment: I fail to see how Cell is a last resort when it has no runtime cost. The choice between using a different approach or using Cell comes down to preference.

Comment: The issue is not the runtime-cost, it is the circumvention of Rust's borrow-check rules, which do not only help protect against memory unsafety, but also against unintended behavior that results from modifying the same memory location in arbitrary locations instead of just where you have a `&mut` reference. Think about it a little like the `mutable` keyword on C++ class members. Your non-mutable objects suddenly are allowed to be modified.

Comment: I agree that a Cell should not publicly be exposed to users - but as building block for abstractions it's perfectly fine.

Comment: 1) It allows logical errors of multiple writes that may be unwanted 2) It's only zero cost to an approximation, in reality it will not / may not optimize as well. Subject to changes in llvm and rustc, of course.

Comment: Currently, this is the only answer that answered my original question. Though, as it's been discussed here, it may not be the safest solution it is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It entirely depends on your `next_gen` function. Assuming we know nothing about the function except its signature, the easiest way is to use indices:

```
fn step(board: &mut Board) {
    for row_index in 0..board.len() {
        for column_index in 0..board[row_index].len() {
            let cell_next = next_gen((row_index, column_index), &board);
            if board[row_index][column_index] != cell_next {
                board[row_index][column_index] = cell_next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With more information about `next_gen` a different solution might be possible, but it sounds a lot like a cellular automaton to me, and to the best of my knowledge this cannot be done in an iterator-way in Rust without changing the type of `Board`.

You might fear that the indexing solution will be less efficient than an iterator solution, but you should trust LLVM on this. In case your `next_gen` function is in another crate, you should mark it `#[inline]` so LLVM can optimize it too (not necessary if everything is in one crate).

---

Not an answer to your question, but to your problem:

Since you are implementing Conway's Game of Life, you cannot do the modification in-place. Imagine the following pattern:

```
00000
00100
00100
00100
00000
```

If you update line 2, it will change the `1` in that line to a `0` since it has only two `1`s in its neighborhood. This will cause the middle `1` to see only two `1`s instead of the three that were there to begin with. Therefor you always need to either make a copy of the entire `Board`, or, as you did in your code, write all the changes to some other location, and splice them in after going through the entire board.

Comment: Yes, this would be the simplest solution but I just wanted to see any alternative ways to do it with iterators. Btw, the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea4b440c9bf77f49592e#file-main-rs-L53)

Comment: it's impossible with iterators unless you create your own iterator (and probably board-type) that is specifically tailored to your Cell-update-function. On a related note, Unless your update-function only accesses cells to the right and the bottom of the current cell, you will get really weird behavior, and definitely not a synchronous cellular automaton. Game of life will be impossible to implement this way.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be a problem. Thanks for that. I haven't been focusing too much on the actual problem of implementing Conway's Game of Life but rather been trying to learn Rust.